# Python - Can't read dictionary values from CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I have two variations of CSV files. One of them uses double quotes, the other one doesn't.

```
A: "shipment_id","status","to_name","to_address_1" etc

B: shipment_id,status,to_name,to_address_1 etc
```

How can read the CSV and print out the value for `shipment_id` regardless of which type of CSV is submitted?

My code doesn't seem to work when the CSV doesn't use double quotes.

```
with open(file_location) as f_obj:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f_obj, delimiter=',')
    for line in reader:
         print(line['shipment_id'])
```

Comment: What you listed as your data doesn’t look like a dict ... please provide a better example.

Comment: @sb0709 huh? OP explained it's a csv. Why did you think it was a `dict`?

Comment: Not so clear based on the sample data: A: "shipment_id","status","to_name","to_address_1" etc so creates impression of csv of multiple dict ...

Comment: It does work here.

Comment: I think the OP is looking to get the data from "csv" into a dict ... because this is the reason of the DictReader so did some testing and the code works and probably is only the data into csv the problem of not outputting, or need to be specified the column names on the read or format the "csv" to include the names for each column.  Here is output I see from the proper formatted "csv" OrderedDict([('shipment_id', '1233'), ('status', 'No'), ('to_name', 'N'), ('to_address_1', 'C')])

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
with open(file_location) as f_obj:
    f_obj = f_obj.read().replace('"','').splitlines()
    reader = csv.DictReader(f_obj, delimiter=',')
    for line in reader:
         print(line['shipment_id'])
```

`.replace('"', '')` will work if it has double quotes, and it will do nothing if it doesn't.

Let me know if it works :)

Answer (score 0):

*Based on what I think the .csv file should look like and experience from pandas read_csv, decided to give my input as follow*

> example of the test.csv file

```
"1233",No,N,C
9999,OK,C,N
```

> example of the test1.csv file

```
"321",ok,P,A
980,No,A,G
"1980","No",A,"G"
```

**Code with specified *fieldnames* for *test.csv* with print(line['shipment_id']):**

```
import csv
with open('test.csv') as f_obj:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f_obj, delimiter=',', fieldnames=['shipment_id','status','to_name','to_address_1'])
    for line in reader:
        print(line['shipment_id'])
```

**output:**

```
1233
9999
```

**Code with specified *fieldnames* for *test1.csv* with print(line['shipment_id']):**

```
with open('test1.csv') as f_obj:
    reader_ddQ = csv.DictReader(f_obj, delimiter=',', fieldnames=['shipment_id','status','to_name','to_address_1'])
    for line in reader_ddQ:
        print(line['shipment_id'])
```

**output:**

```
321
980
1980
```

**Code with specified *fieldnames* for *test1.csv* with print(line):**

```
with open('test1.csv') as f_obj:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f_obj, delimiter=',', fieldnames=['shipment_id','status','to_name','to_address_1'])
    for line in reader:
        print(line)
```

**output:**

```
OrderedDict([('shipment_id', '321'), ('status', 'ok'), ('to_name', 'P'), ('to_address_1', 'A')])
OrderedDict([('shipment_id', '980'), ('status', 'No'), ('to_name', 'A'), ('to_address_1', 'G')])
OrderedDict([('shipment_id', '1980'), ('status', 'No'), ('to_name', 'A'), ('to_address_1', 'G')])
```

Source for the [csv.DictReader](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `quotechar` as parameter:

```
reader = csv.DictReader(f_obj, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
```

(or maybe `'\"'` - I don't know how Python handles this).

This should work on both versions of your data.

If `DictReader` doen't support the `quotechar` parameter, try to use it on `csv.reader` directly.